# Go through values in range, search for them in range, find value in respective rows, add them to array

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I would like to go through a range of values in Column D and take each value:

1. for each value
2. check in the same range for its occurrence
3. check in the row of its occurrence for a value in column A
4. Add this value in column a to an array (or another way to save data)
5. go to the next occurrence of the value in column D and save the next Value of Column A to the array
6. When I checked each value for all its occurrences and added it to the array I want the array to be given out in the cell H1 (and for the next values onwards, I1 and so on)

Here's a picture of what I mean with some dummy values:

[image: Example]

My attempts in VBA so far are this (with the remark that I deal with arrays for the first time):

```
Dim finden As String, FirstFound As String
Dim FoundCell As Range, rng As Range
Dim i As Integer
Dim zahl As Integer
Dim zeile As Range
Dim temparray As Double
Dim b As Integer
Dim count As Integer

Set rng = Worksheets("Tabelle1").Range("H1:H100")
i = Worksheets("Tabelle1").Cells(Rows.count, "D").End(xlUp).Row

For zahl = 1 To i
finden = Sheets("Tabelle1").Cells(zahl, "D").Value
count = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("A1:A100"), finden)
Set zeile = Sheets("Tabelle1").Columns("D").Find(finden, Cells(Rows.count, "D"), xlValues, xlWhole)
If Not zeile Is Nothing Then
    FoundCell = zeile.Address
    Do
        For b = 1 To count
        Set temparray(b, 1) = Sheets("Tabelle1").Cells(zeile.Row, "A").Value
        Set zeile = Sheets("Tabelle1").Columns("A").Find(finden, zeile, xlValues, xlWhole)
        Next b
    Loop While zeile.Address <> FoundCell
   End If
Set zeile = Nothing
rng.Value = temparray
Sheets("Tabelle1").Cells(1, 8 + zahl) = rng.Value
Next

End Sub
```

Unfortunately I already get a error message for:

```
set temparray(b,1)
```

telling me a data field was expected.

Any idea how I could solve my problem?

Comment: You have temporary defined as a double.  Dim temparray As Double  A double is for storing large floating point values.

Comment: Change `Dim temparray as Double` to `Dim temparray() as Double` (do you *really want* double as your data type?). Change `set temparray(b,1)` to `temparray(b,1)` and add `ReDim Preserve temparray(b-1,1)` before that statement ... Also read about how to work with arrays a bit more ... :)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the `Collection` object as it is a good way to store unique values. You don't need to run the multiple `Find` functions or incrementally build your array, you could simply read the columns once and write them into the relevant collection.

It's had to tell from your question and code how you want to write the output, but the code below will set you in the right direction:

```
Dim uniques As Collection
Dim valueSet As Collection
Dim valueD As String
Dim valueA As String
Dim v As Variant
Dim r As Long
Dim c As Long
Dim output() As String

'Read the data
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tabelle1")
    v = .Range("A1", _
        .Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp)) _
        .Value2
End With

'Populate the collections
Set uniques = New Collection
For r = 1 To UBound(v, 1)

    valueA = CStr(v(r, 1))
    valueD = CStr(v(r, 4))

    'Check if we have a collection for the D value
    Set valueSet = Nothing
    On Error Resume Next
    Set valueSet = uniques(valueD)
    On Error GoTo 0

    'If not then create a new one.
    If valueSet Is Nothing Then
        Set valueSet = New Collection
        uniques.Add valueSet, Key:=valueD
    End If

    'Add the A value to it
    valueSet.Add valueA
Next

'Compile the write array
ReDim Preserve output(1 To 1, 1 To uniques.Count)
c = 1
For Each valueSet In uniques
    For Each v In valueSet
        '--> uncomment this 'If block', if you want
        '--> comma separated values.
'            If Len(output(1, c)) > 0 Then
'                output(1, c) = output(1, c) & ", "
'            End If
        output(1, c) = output(1, c) & v
    Next
    c = c + 1
Next

'Write the output array
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tabelle1") _
    .Range("H1").Resize(, UBound(output, 2)) _
    .Value = output
```